# Excel - Sumproduct with 2 conditions

Tags: excel-formula

Thanks to the community a couple of days ago I am now using the following formula to count the number of rooms that belong to a given room type.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(R2:R3000,Z2:Z300))
```

- Where Column R is a list of room numbers
- Column Z is a list of room numbers belonging to a room type.

This is working correctly however our Property Management system is including some erroneous data that is adding additional records that do not need to be counted. The 2nd condition I want to add is:

Check the value in column T (room nights) to ensure that is >= 1.

*From other posts I can see that you need to multiply the 2 conditions but haven't got this to work. Do I need just the 1 or 2 countif functions?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting the [COUNTIF function](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/COUNTIF-function-E0DE10C6-F885-4E71-ABB4-1F464816DF34)  to a [COUNTIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-53C4DC8E-0E5B-4E32-93DF-9CA5E7DA89ED) should be sufficient.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(R2:R3000, Z2:Z300, T2:T3000, ">"&0))
```

Comment: Thanks Jeeped, works perfectly. Could you help me understand why the additional symbols are needed for the 2nd conditional?

Comment: A countif interprets its conditions; that way a `"1"` is equal to a `1`, something that is not generally true. You cannot use `T2:T3000>0` like you would in other situations. See the linked docs I provided for additional examples.

Comment: Thanks, your explanation helped a lot.